# Find all files (including libraries) a binary depends on

Tags: dependencies, binary

I'd like to **find all files a binary depends on** (including libraries, configuration files, basically all files referenced in the binary).

I know, that you can find **shared libraries** with `objdump, ldd, readelf`, **but what about dynamically loaded libraries (`dlopen`) and other files (`/etc/some/config`)?**

So far, I have a half baked solution which searches the binary for strings (filenames) (`$ strings /path/to/binary | grep lib`), but I think the proper solution would be to search for system calls the binary makes (`read, write, dlopen, etc`).

Unfortunately I don't have any experience with disassemblers or an idea about other methods.

Also I cannot use solutions which depend on executing the binary (strace, and fiddling around, etc), because I need to do this for a large number of binaries in bulk.

A solution which finds about 90% of all files referenced by a binary would be sufficient.

The binaries to examine are standard (Arch) Linux (multilib) binaries. I assume most of them were compiled by gcc (-O2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
strace -fe open cmd 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -v '= -1' | cut -d\" -f2
```

To see what it opens at run time.